# Qt - Download Data from url

Tags: qt, qurl

I wrote a web service with PHP. I need download content via web service URL. How can I download data from URL?

Which libraries are needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add `QT += network` in .pro project file
2. Include below libraries to your code:

   ```
   #include <QUrl>
   #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
   #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
   #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
   ```
3. At the end receive URL content via following code:

   ```
   QString url = "WEB_SERVICE_URL";
   QNetworkAccessManager manager;
   QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
   QEventLoop event;
   connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
   event.exec();
   QString content = response->readAll();
   ```